# Configuring the canonicalization algorithm in WebLogic 11g SAML2 identity provider

Tags: weblogic, single-sign-on, saml, weblogic11g, saml-2.0

I'm implementing a .NET SAML2 service provider using the Microsoft WIF SAML2 protocol extension. Our partner's identity provider signs their responses using http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments canonicalization algorithm. It turned out Microsoft's SAML2 protocol implementation only supports http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#. Our partner is using WebLogic 11g. Is there a way to configure WebLogic's canonicalization algorithm?

Comment: im stuck on this same problem!